# Magento Product Increments Value

Tags: product, qty-increment

I have a large number of products I need to add different qty increment values for.  I cannot find this value in the database, nor do I see a way to upload this value in the admin.  What am I doing wrong, How can I add Qty Increment values for a large number of products at once.

Hint: My increments vary per product.

Comment: what do you mean by qty increment values?

Comment: You can write a condition in your code, I don't think you are able to set different increments the default is 1 so you should have an observer event and say increment it by the conditions you want to set

Comment: are Qty Increments values  fixed all products?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a CSV upload. Use column sku for the item sku (naturally) and add these four columns:

```
use_config_qty_increments   :Choose whether the Config settings will be applied for the Qty Increments option (0 = no)
qty_increments              :The incrementation required for item in shopping cart
use_config_enable_qty_inc   :To use Config settings for enable_qty_increments (0 = no)
enable_qty_increments       :Is the customer restricted to adding items in qty_increments (1 = yes)
```